# Homestead up and provision wipes databases

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead

When using homestead for laravel projects it keeps deleting any databases that are created on the box. Is is possible to retain databases when halting / destroying the homestead box so that they still appear once homestead up or provision is run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should suspend the box if you want to keep the databases: `vagrant suspend`. Then when you are ready to use it again you can use `vagrant up`

If you destroy the box, then re-create it - all the databases will be gone.

Comment: What if i shut down my machine? Provision will destroy the databases wont it?

Comment: No - because you only `provision` the box once. You then `suspend` the box every time after that. When suspended, the computer is safe to turn off/on. You shouldnt be provisioning the box daily - just once every now and again. I havent provisioned my box for 6 months.

Comment: But if i need to add a new project, map a new files etc. Is it not provision i use then? I have been following a few seperate tutorials so i am adding new sites a few times a month between new ones and starting from scratch